# Unknown column 'action' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a database on myphpadmin and i try to make a simple update  but i keep getting the same error. I checked around the internet for some time but nothing helped.
i try this

```
UPDATE `employees` SET `FirstName`= "Mike" where 1
```

Employees has the attribue FirstName inside any help?

Comment: Show your table structure, will help more about your problem..

Comment: Based on your info you're using MySQL so I added a corresponding tag to your question.

Comment: What is your `WHERE 1` supposed to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is an employee_id column, try;

```
UPDATE `employees` SET `FirstName`= "Mike" where employee_id = 1
```

just use the correct column name  :)